# Cayley: How do insert vertices and edges into graph using Cayley-Gremlin code?

Tags: javascript, go, graph-databases, gremlin, cayley

So being new to Go and Cayley I am struggling with inserting data into the graph. I am running a gremlin console on the command line with this command:

```
cayley repl --db="bolt" --dbpath=../../database/database1 --query_lang="gremlin"
```

I know cayley uses a different variant of Gremlin. This page (https://github.com/google/cayley/wiki) states that it uses 'Cayley-Gremlin' instead of 'Tinkerpop-Gremlin'. I would think that for the most part the API would remain the same, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This [documentation](http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/graph-addvertex) states that the graph object has an `addVertex` method available. However, when I try to use the method in the Cayley repl I get an error:

```
cayley> g.addVertex("test")

Error: TypeError: 'addVertex' is not a function
-----------
1 Results
Elapsed time: 0.102239 ms
```

Why is the method not available on the graph? Is the API different? Is there another method of inserting nodes/edges into graphs using 'Cayley-Gremlin'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gremlin in cayley is only for traversals.  https://github.com/google/cayley/blob/master/docs/GremlinAPI.md is the complete gremlin API for cayley.

use http to add data: https://github.com/google/cayley/blob/master/docs/HTTP.md#apiv1write

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to cayley but I thought that

```
cayley> :a subject predicate object label .
```

Was a command of gremlin to add new vertex executed from repl (for me, a much more convenient way to do adding and deleting (`:d`)